# How does Doc Ock stay awake after being punched by Spider-Man?

Tags: spider-man-trilogy, spider-man-2

In Spider-Man 2, Spider-Man repeatedly punches Doc Ock, yet Ock still remains conscious. Isn't he supposed to be knocked out considering he is still a normal human and Spider-Man is pretty strong? In the comics, the one time Spider-Man landed a good punch on Doc Ock, it knocked him out cold, even Spider-Man was surprised.

**How does this movie Doc Ock resist the Spider-powered hits?**

Comment: Same question on Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77498/how-did-doctor-octopus-survive-even-one-punch-from-spiderman-in-spiderman-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because plot?

It's not a great answer, but I think it's the logical one. They could have made Doctor Octopus seem like the strongest person in the universe, but if Spiderman could have knocked him out with a single punch it would have looked a little ridiculous. We would have had a film with Spiderman running away/getting beaten up the entire time, until the last fight when he landed a single punch and saved the day.

It's just a little too silly - instead, they make him seem like he can take a few blows and really can hold his own.

This also is a good cinematic technique to bolster the character of Doctor Octopus as a true danger to Peter - even when he has him pinned down and is punching him, Dr Octopus can overpower him. It heightens the sense of danger and establishes him as a worthy opponent.

Comment: *"it would have looked a little ridiculous"* Not an excuse, IMO: knocking him out might not have even affected the fight much because the mechanical arms *had a will of their own* and could've gone on fighting anyway. They took out an entire OR when Ock was under.